# Is there a way to move an Azure Api Management instance to different datacenter?

Tags: azure-api-management

We have an API Management instance with users and traffic in one datacenter. We would like to move this instance to another datacenter. There seems to be no way of doing this directly through the Azure portal.

We've tried to scale out the API management instance to the desired data center. However, the original instance is not possible to delete since it functions as some sort of 'master' instance. We've also tried backing upp the instance and restoring it to a new instance according to this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-disaster-recovery-backup-restore

This works pretty good, but gives us some other issues since we need to close down the portal for some time to avoid an unsynchronized backup. Further, our DNS needs to be updated.

Is there any alternative to backing up and restoring? What would be best practice to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no zero-downtime way to do that. Backup-restore is your best option.